# Spark Program queries executing via Tez engine instead of Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have a Spark program which executes multiple queries and the tables are Hive tables.

Currently the queries are executed using Tez engine from Spark.

I set it sqlContext.sql("SET hive.execution.engine=spark") in the program and understand that the queries/program would run as Spark. We are using HDP 2.6.5 version and Spark 2.3.0 version in our cluster.

Can someone suggest that it is the correct way as we do not need to run the queries using Tez engine and Spark should run as it is .

In the config file /etc/spark2/conf/hive-site.xml, we do not have any specific engine property setup and we do have only kerberos, metastore property details.

Comment: Could you find `hive-site.xml` in `/somepath/hive/conf/hive-site.xml` ?

Comment: We are trying run Hive queries via Spark SQL program and in our case we do not need TEZ engine to run those hive queries. How do we enforce that in Spark that should not use Tez as execution engine for queries in Spark which uses Hive table.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to set anything. Run a SparkSQL query, and open the Tez UI, and you will not see anything related to the Spark execution there.

If you do, then you can try to set `hive-site.xml` config for Spark, and add `hive.execution.engine` value there.